# Fabric not responding to keyboard input

Tags: python, ssh, user-input, fabric

Hey All: I have a Fabric based program running whose job is to upload, compile, and run a c program (test.c) on a remote server. For the uploading I am just using the WinSCP command line tool and the subprocess module.

I should note that I am testing this program inside PyCharm.

For the compiling and running I am using a Fabric connection. It works, unless my program has some sort of input in it. For example, test.c is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("This is running on the server It is a new file..\n\nEnter a character: ");
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("It worked!. Your number is ... %d!\n", i);
}
```

Here is the relevant python code.

```py
import sys
import subprocess

from fabric import Connection
from json import loads

info = loads(open('pwd.json').read())

def run():
    # Upload the file. [Omitted]
    print('Uploaded file!')
    c = Connection(host='glue.umd.edu', user=info['username'],
                   connect_kwargs={'password': info['password']})
    with c.cd('python_environment'):
        result = c.run(f'gcc {filename} -Wall')
        print(result.stdout)
        print('Compiled! Running...')
        result = c.run(f'a.out', echo=True, echo_stdin=True, pty=True)
    print("Closing...")
    c.close()
    print("Completed!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = 'test.c'
    if 'run' in sys.argv:
        run()
```

And of course, the result.

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:9:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^

Compiled! Running...
cd python_environment && a.out
This is running on the server It is a new file..

Enter a character:
```

Entering a number and then enter does not work. I have manually ran the program on the server using PuTTY and it does work as expected. Typing in a number and then 'Enter' will print out the number on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.

For anyone looking at this in the future: solved by running the program outside of PyCharm, or by selecting "emulate terminal in output console".